# Cannot start container with docker compose up

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to Dockerize an application and it's my first time. Have a Docker file inside the working directory:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev python3-dev


COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

and I have this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "1.1"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  backend:
    build: /
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/backend
    env_file: .env
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
  frontend:
    build: frontend/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ../frontend/src:/frontend/src
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Every time I try and run docker compose build or docker compose up I get the following error:

```
failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3961901539/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Why is it looking for the Dockerfile in that location if it is right here in the WORKDIR?

Is there a way to clear it and just start over with the dockerfile in the current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your backend service, you're telling docker compose that the dockerfile is in the root directory with

```
build: /
```

It should be in the current directory, so change it to

```
build: .
```

Comment: Thanks can you tell me what this means pls:     volumes:
      - ./:/backend

Comment: It's a 'bind mount' that makes the current directory on the host (`./`) available inside the container on the path `/backend`. https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: That `volumes:` block overwrites all of the code in the image with content from the host.  That means that what you're running locally isn't what's actually in the image when you go to deploy it, and it can result in inconsistencies if you get the path mapping wrong or need to do more setup in the Dockerfile.  I'd recommend removing it.

Comment: I changed the build: to . and the first time it ran but there was a problem with the path to the front end app. Now when I try and run it I get the same tmp file not found error:
failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount735560206/Dockerfile: no such file or directory